# AngularJS Component Not Rendering

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.11.

I can't seem to get my component wired-up correctly. If I hard-code a template property, it works:

```
$stateProvider.state("dashboard.expense", {
  url: "/expense",
  template: `<div>Geddy Lee</div>`
})
```

^^ That indeed shows `Geddy Lee` on the page.

But as soon as I point it to a component, no rendering occurs:

```
$stateProvider.state("dashboard.expense", {
  url: "/expense",
  component: "expenseReportsComponent"
})
```

I'm keeping the component simple, just to see if I can get it to render:

```
module.component('expenseReportsComponent', {
  template: `<div>Geddy Lee</div>`
});
```

^^ `Geddy Lee` is not displayed.

There are no console errors. I've tried a variety of changes, but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check to see what version of ui-router you are using. I believe the component property was added in 1.0.0.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 3):

You are very likely to use old version of `ui-router`. Either migrate to newer one or use:

```
template: `<expense-reports-component></expense-reports-component>`
```

you wont have all features like `uiOnParamsChanged` in this case, but this of course will work.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried using the `template` property like that and it didn't work for me. Looks like I just need to update `ui-router`.

Answer (score 0):

Combine it all together and use both template and component in your state declaration:

```
$stateProvider.state("dashboard.expense", {
  url: "/expense",
  template: `<div>Geddy Lee</div>`,
  component: "expenseReportsComponent"
})
```

Comment: I don't think that helps me. This is just a test to see that I can get a component working. Once I do, I'm going to start using a more complex component. Plus, I believe the `component` property is supposed to take the place of the `template` and `controller` properties.